# Runtime request permission in NativeScript Android app

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I code an application in Native Script and I need to use requestPermission after first launch app. I know how to use request permission, but I don't know how to make it work after first running the application. Where I must use request-permission function in app ? In ngOnInit () ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [nativescript-permissions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-permissions) plugin to acquire runtime permissions on Android.

Use `hasPermission(permissionName);` method to know whether your app already has the permission Or you are yet to acquire it.

Generally it's recommended to ask for permission only when it's absolute necessary. For example, if you want to access micro phone to record anything you would request for permission only when user tries to record one, not upon launch.

You could still ask permissions upon launch, that would work. But in my opinion that could be annoying to the user. May be he is not intended to use that particular feature of the app but just the rest.

Comment: I am writing an application in which the user chooses the options between the camera and the gallery. Gallery requires multimedia rights. The camera requires multimedia and camera rights. So I found that the user can grant these rights after starting the application for two functions at once

Comment: Where I must use `hasPermission(permissionName); ` in code ? In ngOnInit function  ?

Comment: `ngOnInit` on app component may be too early some times. You may use the [application level events](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/application-lifecycle#use-application-events) like `launchEvent`, `displayedEvent` etc.,

Answer (score 0):

// HTML

```
<Button text="Take Permissions" (tap)="getPermission()"></Button>
```

// TS File

```
import * as camera from "nativescript-camera";



getPermission() {
    camera.requestPermissions().then(
      function success() {
        console.log('granted');
      }, 
      function failure() {
        console.log('failure');
      }
      );
  }
```

// Search AndroidManifest.xml and add this code in all the occurrences.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

That's all!